# How to forward a REST web service using C# (WCF)?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

There is a web service that can only be consumed via http and a client that can only consume https web services. Therefore I need some intermediary that forwards on requests received in https and returns responses in http.

Supposing that the intermediary is completely dumb save for the fact that it knows where the web service endpoint is (i.e. it doesn't know what the signature of the service is, it just knows that it can communicate with it via an http web request, and it listens on some https uri, forwarding on anything it receives), what is the most simple way of achieving this?

I've been playing around with this all day and am not sure how to achieve the "dumb" bit, i.e. not knowing the signature for passing back the verbatim response.

Comment: Are you sure about the HTTP/HTTPS restriction? HTTPS is still HTTP, just over a secure connection. You might be able to solve your problem just by using port forwarding from 443 to 80 (assuming the client accepts plain HTTP responses)

Comment: I've been told that port-forwarding is not an option. Not sure why this is, but it is part of the spec; might be because the client is outside the company intranet so can't return by http.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Isn't it just doing an HTTP POST with the original SOAP payload from the client (possibly after removing the client credentials) to the final endpoint and returning the response back?

Comment: @muratgu: The problem is likely that the WCF endpoint has already consumed the payload from the client by converting it into an object of some sort.  WCF is probably going to fight against you in a case like this.

Comment: @mellamokb: Yes that is my issue. How to return the "payload" unadulterated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dumb intermediary is essentially a proxy.  Your best bet might to be just use standard asp.net pages (instead of shoehorning into service functionality like ASMX or WCF which are just going to fight you) so you can receive the request exactly as-is and process it in a simple way using standard request/response.  You can make use of `HttpWebRequest` class to forward the request on to the other endpoint.

1. Client requests https://myserver.com/forwarder.aspx?forwardUrl=http://3rdparty.com/api/login
2. myserver.com (your proxy) reads querystring `forwardUrl` and any POST or GET request included.
3. myserver.com requests to http://3rdparty.com/api/login and passes along GET or POST data sent from the client.
4. myserver.com takes response and sends back as response to other endpoint (essentially just `Response.Write` contents out to the response)

You would need to write forwarder.aspx to process the requests.  Code for `forwarder.aspx` would be something like this (untested):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var forwardUrl = Request.QueryString["forwardUrl"];
    var post = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    var req = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(forwardUrl);
    new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()).Write(post);
    var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    var result = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream).ReadToEnd();
    Response.Write(result);  // send result back to caller
}
```

Comment: That was the direction I was moving in. Thanks for that I'll try it now and report back.

Comment: You might want to learn how to use Fiddler to help track the traffic and diagnose issues if something doesn't work: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/.  Also, something I didn't think of is if the API uses cookies for session tracking, that will have to be handled as well.

Comment: Cheers, that's done the job. Doing it via a proxy website is definitely the right approach to take! I've also managed to extend the code so that it handles SOAP too. Hopefully I won't need to fiddle the cookies, but I'll find out on Monday when someone actually give me a spec. And during my travels I found this http://membrane-soa.org/soap-router.htm Which I'm hoping to sell the IT guys instead of my homebrew website option that I just know will all end in tears down the line and me getting it in the neck.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks again for this. Turned out once the thing was deployed that it was a SOAP request, not REST (*Obviously*, I was just given a URL and told to make it work). However this approach works for both and being able to access it in a RESTful way was very handy from a debugging point of view.